# LLVM replace an instruction using ReplaceInstWithValue when iterating

Tags: c++, iterator, clang, llvm

I'm new to LLVM, and I want to use the function `ReplaceInstWithValue()` to delete some useless instructions.

Let's see the following example:

```
define dso_local i32 @foo(i32 %0, i32 %1) #0 {
  %3 = add nsw i32 %1, 0
  %4 = add nsw i32 %0, 0
  %5 = add nsw i32 %3, 1
  %6 = add nsw i32 %5, 1
  %7 = add nsw i32 %6, 0
  ret i32 %7
}
```

There are some useless instructions such as `%3 = add nsw i32 %1, 0`, this is because I generate bytecode by the command `clang-12 -O0 -Xclang -disable-O0-optnone -emit-llvm -c main.c -o main.bc`. I know that delete an iterater when iterating it is forbidden, so I write a very ugly code below:

```
    bool Changed = true;
    while(Changed){
      Changed = false;
      for(auto BBIter = F.begin(); BBIter != F.end(); BBIter++){
        auto &BB = *BBIter;
        for(auto InstIter = BB.begin(); InstIter != BB.end(); InstIter++){
          auto &Inst = *InstIter;
          auto Res = isAlgebracIdentity(Inst);
          auto IsAlgebrac = Res.first;
          Value * V = Res.second;
          if(IsAlgebrac){
            ReplaceInstWithValue(BB.getInstList(), InstIter, V);
            BB.print(outs());
            Changed = true;
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

This is a very brute-force approach, so I wonder any better way to deal with it?

Comment: FWIW, the thing that's (nearly) forbidden is modifying a list while iterating over the same list. That can be done but it's a bug magnet. Very easy to make mistakes. But keep in mind that calling something to make the modification for you isn't less complex and easier to understand. It seems to me what you're using RIWV as a replacement for [deleteValue()](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Value.html#a99d640257f7689aa8095dccfb111e50c) and will likely have the same bugs. The typical pattern I see in good code is ① iterate to decide what to do and *after* that, ② delete/replace/act.

Comment: I know what you mean, the way you said is something like using a worklist to record what we need to delete/replace. However, if we did so, the deleted/replaced instructions will have an effect on the following instructions, so I decided not to do so. Maybe some tricks are not found by me.

Comment: Yes, worklists are common. Something like what @jmmartinez suggests will work, but of course, if you modify the instructions that use "your" instruction, then you may still modify the list item to which the iterator points. For example, if you use RIWV(), then next year someone may add constant folding to RIWV() and the folding will then have a low-probability chance of invalidating your iterator.

Answer (score 0):

You could increase the iterator before removing the "current" instruction.

Something like this:

```cpp
bool Changed = true;
while(Changed) {
  Changed = false;
  for(BasicBlock &BB : F) {

    auto InstIter = BB.begin();
    while(InstIter != BB.end()) {
      Instruction &Inst = *InstIter;
      auto Res = isAlgebracIdentity(Inst);
      bool IsAlgebrac = Res.first;
          
      ++InstIter; // increase the iterator

      if (IsAlgebrac) {
        Value * V = Res.second;
        // erase the instruction before InstIter
        ReplaceInstWithValue(BB.getInstList(), Inst.getIterator(), V);
        Changed = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'll have a try, thank you~